# SELECT query using JPAContainerFactory created Entity Manager creates INSERT INTO query

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have the following orders table. (I removed most of the columns for readability)

```sql
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `surprice_id` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `car_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_car_group` FOREIGN KEY (`car_group_id`) REFERENCES `car_group` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_orders_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

I have a sync method where I get an external list of orders and iterate through them and check the "surprice_id" to see if this order is already in my system.
This is the query I use

```java
List<Orders> orders = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE surprice_id = '" + surpriceId + "'", Orders.class).getResultList();
```

This is the Entity Manager I use

```java
EntityManager em = JPAContainerFactory.createEntityManagerForPersistenceUnit("pu");
```

"PU" is the name of my Persistence Unit that I have declared in my persistence.xml

If the size of the list, after the query, is 0 then I add it to my system otherwise I update the details.
For some reason, at a specific surprice_id the query returns an exception.

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'car_group_id' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO orders (broker_code, collection_address, collection_message, creation_date, delivery_address, delivery_message, departure_airport, end_actual, end_date, ext_end_date, ext_start_date, extra_data, flight_number, notes, sold_as_upgrade, start_actual, start_date, status, surprice_id, version, area_from_id, area_to_id, broker_id, car_group_id, customer_id, first_driver_id, second_driver_id, staff_collection_id, staff_delivery_id, station_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [30 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.model.Orders[ id=null ])
```

You can see that for some reason the "CALL" is for an INSERT INTO query.
I debug into my code and when I evaluate this part

```java
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE surprice_id = '" + surpriceId + "'", Orders.class)
```

I can see that the generated databseQuery is

```sql
ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Orders sql="SELECT * FROM orders WHERE surprice_id = 'SCR386148'")
```

But the moment I add the `.getResultList()` at the end, I get the aforementioned error.
During debugging I've check other ids that don't exist in my database, and I just get a 0 sized result list, so I'm really baffled by what might be causing this behavior...

Any ideas on where I should turn my attention to?

Answer (score 0):

Before the execution of a query, EclipseLink checks if the result of the query might be affected by the entities that belong to the session but haven't been saved in the db yet. If that's the case, it does a flush of the session before running the query.

It seems that before running the native query, you've persisted an order.
EclipseLink knows that the query will affect the entity `Order`, so it will make sure that the previous persist operation is executed before running the native query.
Otherwise the previous not yet persisted order will never appear in the query.
Maybe in this case it doesn't matter, but in other situations it might not be the case.

Before using `.getResultList()`, no query is executed and so there is no need to flush.

I suspect that something is wrong in the way you are creating that order that causes the constraint violation

Comment: I'll go through the code again and check what happens before getting to the problematic iteration. Thank you for your input.